# Multiple word anagram checker

Tags: c++, arrays

I was given the assignment of expanding on my current code (one that takes two words from user's input and checks to see if they are anagrams or not).

The code takes the user's input, then, one word at a time, fills an array. If the arrays match at the end, then they are anagram.

```
int check(char a[], char b[])
{
    int first[26] = { 0 }, second[26] = { 0 }, c = 0;

    while (a[c] != '\0')
    {
        first[a[c] - 'a']++;
        c++;
    }

    c = 0;

    while (b[c] != '\0')
    {
        second[b[c] - 'a']++;
        c++;
    }

    for (c = 0; c < 26; c++)
    {
        if (first[c] != second[c])
            return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

My predicament now is that I don't know how to do the "20 words part".

We are supposed to take the 20 words (for example "art", "tar", "cat", "fat", "dat", "ats") and put them into an array. Then we take another array and make it the number of unique words, i.e., words that are the first of their kind.

Example: "art" and "cat" are unique, but if you include "tar", then "tar" is not unique.

It will count the number of words that are anagrams to the unique words, and at then end show all the words in groups of anagrams.

To do this, I suspect that my previous code will have to change a whole bunch, and I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 0):

You can regenerate a word from your frequency array, which will be unique.

These can be simply sorted alphabetically. Ex :-

tar :  art

rat :  art


Or you can code the frequency followed by letter :-

tar : 1a1r1t           (1 'a', 1 'r' and 1 't' )

apple : 1a1e1l2p


Now you can put these generated words in an array and check for duplicates, or you can use a set to get the unique count.

Comment: The second method you gave me is the one I am supposed to incorporate I believe. How would one go about with setting the set to the unique count, and how would one set up most or organization.